# Lite server without config file

Tags: angularjs, json, npm, browser-sync, lite-server

I'm using [lite server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) for developing my Angular projects. It depends on and uses [BrowserSync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync) to do most of the work (serving the site to localhost, live reload etc).

Currently, I have a config file `bs-config.json` in my root for this module:

```
{ 
  "injectChanges": true,
  "files": ["./**/*.{html,css,js,png,jpg,svg,gif}"],
  "watchOptions": { 
    "ignored": [
      "node_modules",
      "src/**/*.*",
      "app/**/*.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then in my `package.json` I have a script to execute it, referring to the config file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server -c bs-config.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Works great. But ideally I don't want a config file in the root of my project that isn't used in production. Is it possibly to extend the `script` in my `package.json` to execute the config inline with the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, its not possible to extend the `dev` script in your `package.json` to execute the config inline when using lite-server.

If you don't want a config file in the root of your project, you would simply place it elsewhere in your project (i.e., in a folder called `configs`) and provide a custom path to your config file via `-c` or `--config` run time options. So your `dev` script will be `"lite-server -c configs/bs-config.json"`.

Check out this GitHub issue: [Command line arguments no longer supported?](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/80)